# How can I take an action on form submit when .submit is already being used?

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, form-submit

I have a form that I do not control - it is generated by the Easy Digital Downloads plugin as a short code.  It uses ajax to submit the form and return a success message.

I want to do a simple tracking function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( "form" ).submit(function() {
  Intercom('trackEvent', 'Form Submission');
});
</script>
```

However, when I do, it kills the form submission and I don't get the success message and following redirect that are built in to the form already.

Is there another way to track the form submission without interfering with current .submit actions?

Comment: Multiple `submit` handlers should be ok. What is the other handler doing--is it calling `stopImmediatePropagation`? If not, then both handlers should be run.

Comment: I don't know what the other script is doing.  It is in encrypted code.  What happens when I put the script above on the page is that the actions the other script takes stop working.  So normally, you fill out the form, and it then gives you a success message and redirects you to a page where you can edit the info you just submitted.  When I put that code on the page, nothing happens, the form just reloads blank.